# Is it just me or has anyone else noticed that asp.net does not recognize the 2013?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-select

I have a dropdownlist of dates that represent significant functions in our department.

These dates remain the same year in, year out.

Below is the dropdownList of dates:

```
             <asp:DropDownList id="txtdte" runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem Value="07/31/2012">Jul 31, 2012</asp:ListItem>  
              <asp:ListItem Value="08/21/2012">Aug 21, 2012</asp:ListItem>  
              <asp:ListItem Value="09/18/2012">Sep 18, 2012</asp:ListItem>  
              <asp:ListItem Value="11/06/2012">Nov 06, 2012</asp:ListItem>  
              <asp:ListItem Value="12/04/2012">Dec 04, 2012</asp:ListItem>  
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

To ensure that correct date shows at top of the dropdownlist box, we have the following code:

```
    For Each items As ListItem In txtdte.Items
        If (items.Value.CompareTo(DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))) < 0 Then
            items.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```

This means that we start from July 31. Once July 31 is gone, the next available date becomes the current date.

This has been working great for us until now, when management decided to add January's date which is 01/08/2013.

```
              <asp:ListItem Value="01/08/2013">Jan 08, 2013</asp:ListItem>
```

Now, the dropdownlistbox is blank.

It seems to me some tweaking is needed for 2013 to be recognized but I am not sure what.

Any ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this doing string comparison? Therefore `01/08/2013` does sort "less" (or before) `12/13/2012` ("0" is less than "1") and would be disabled?

Comment: Asp.Net uses Maya calender http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_phenomenon

Comment: @Christ Sinclair, you are correct. I suppose it is not possible to miz 2012 and 2013 unless the month portion of 2013 is higher the month portion of the previous year.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh, you could do `.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`, but as in the answer below it would be best to convert to `DateTime` and compare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing this is performing string comparison, where "01/08/2013" as a string compares less than "12/13/2012" (the "0" is alphabetically earlier than "1")

Try changing your code to convert the value from string to date and compare `DateTime` objects rather than their string representation:

```
For Each items As ListItem In txtdte.Items
    If (DateTime.Parse(items.Value).CompareTo(DateTime.Today)) < 0 Then
        items.Enabled = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked @Chris Sinclair. Thanks a lot for your prompt response.